# jQuery Sortable - How to prevent sorting if an item is outside of a container?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have two sortable containers that are adjacent to each other on the page, there is a gap between both containers. How can I ensure that a dragged item that gets dropped in this gap (or anywhere other than over the containers themselves) simply reverts to where it was previously?

```
$(".foobar").sortable({
        appendTo: "body",
        connectWith: ".foobar",
        handle: '.drag',
        items: ".item",
        placeholder: "item-placeholder",
        scroll: true,
        tolerance: "pointer",
        zIndex: 9999999999
    }).disableSelection();
```

Here is a JSFiddle to assist. Drag an item from the left-hand list and hover it over the right-hand list so that the placeholder appears, then move the item over the gap between the two lists and drop it. Currently, it will be inserted into list 2 - I want it to revert back to the left-hand list.
https://jsfiddle.net/c05nfuzh/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/c05nfuzh/